# How to properly write AGE queries with the `RETURN *` Cypher command

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

I am trying to add support for the following query for an AGE project that converts Cypher queries to SQL:

```
MATCH p=({name: 'agens-graph'})-[{lang: 'java'}]->(m) RETURN *;
```

This successfully converts into the following:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('test', $$ MATCH p=({name: 'agens-graph'})-[{lang: 'java'}]->(m) RETURN * $$) AS (v agtype);
```

However, this produces an error:

```
ERROR:  return row and column definition list do not match
```

Assuming I **do not** know the exact columns that will be produced with the `RETURN *`, is there a way to replace the `AS (v agtype)` to something else that will support the query (something like `AS (* agtype)`)? Or is this not yet supported in AGE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation of RETURN clause, even if you are using `RETURN *`, you need to define the number of columns to be returned by the cypher query and so any alike of `* agtype` is not yet supported. For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
MATCH (a {name: 'A'})-[r]->(b)
RETURN *
$$) as (a agtype, b agtype, r agtype);
```

Reference: [RETURN clause](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/clauses/return.html#return-all-elements)

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, `AS (* agtype))` is not yet supported in **AGE**.

Also, the reason for the error `ERROR:  return row and column definition list do not match` is that you did not give the specific number of columns to be returned after using `RETURN *` which returns all elements.

Hence, this query:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('test', $$ MATCH p=({name: 'agens-graph'})-[{lang: 'java'}]->(m) RETURN * $$) AS (v agtype);
```

should be;

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('test', $$ MATCH p=({name: 'agens-graph'})-[{lang: 'java'}]->(m) RETURN * $$) AS (name agtype, lang agtype, m agtype);
```

This way the error would not occur because the number of columns is given.

Answer (score 1):

So far it's not supported that you can return all elements at once without specifying the elements to be returned, although you can `RETURN *`, it still required to specify the elements in `AS (a agtype, b agtype, c agtype);` as following:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('test', $$ MATCH (a)-[r: REL]->(b) RETURN * $$) as (a agtype, b agtype, r agtype);
```

I hope this answers your question :).

Answer (score 1):

You are facing this error because  the columns that the "cypher" function is returning is not equal to the number of columns that are stated in the 'AS' statement. Hence, the function is generating several columns but they are being changed into a single column with the identity 'v'.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM cypher('test', $$ MATCH p=({name: 'agens-graph'})-[{lang: 'java'}]->(m) RETURN * $$)
  AS (data agtype);
```

We have to define what we are getting back as return expects a column number but you can use a placeholder value to keep it dynamic. It is usually advised to know the exact number.

Answer (score 0):

Following this example:

```
MATCH (a {name: 'A'})-[r]->(b)
RETURN a, b, r
```

in:

```
(a {name: 'A'})-[r]->(b)
```

is the pattern you want to match. The RETURN clause specifies that you want to **return** all **three** variables **(a, b, and r)**.